# Lower and upper bounds for fractional linear transformation

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

If we have $k(z)=\frac{z}{1-tz}$ which is convex in unit disk, then $k(\bar{z})=\overline{k(z)}$, $k(z)$ maps real axis to real axis where $|z|\leq{r}$, $t\in\mathbb{R}$. What is the upper and lower bounds of $\Re {k(z)}$?

Comment: If $r\ge1/t$ then there can't be any upper bound since $k\to\infty$ as $z\to1/t$

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing the LFT in the following form:

$$
k(z)=\frac{z}{1-tz} = -\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{t(1-tz)}
$$

Now test with some points in $\mathbb{C}$ such as $\infty,0,1,\frac{1}{t}$ etc.

For some geometric aid, to see Gerry Myerson's comment try [this applet](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/java/Mobius.html). Also you can find your answer by trying out.

Select circle and enter the variables at the bottom with `Enter new values` button.